# UITableViewController or UIViewController

Tags: ios4

What is the difference between UITableViewController and UIViewController. I have to make a tableview based app, so which one should i use? I used UIViewController as protocols, and the table works fine.  But could i benefit in any way by using UITableViewController subclass to begin with?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `UITableViewController`. You can use `UIViewConroller` and add the table view manually, but you'll lose some of the functionality you'd get if you'd use `UITableViewController`. Besides, using the `UITableViewController` is much faster, since everything is set up for you already.